# Why am I getting a nil error?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Currently I can add the current playing song on the iPhone to my app, but I am trying to play a song from Parse based on the song title on the app, but I am getting a nil error. Why?

```
 func playit(sender: UIButton!){
    if let nowPlaying = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem{
    let title = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] as? String
    let artist = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] as? String

    println(title! + artist!)


        let query = PFQuery(className: "Songs")
        query.whereKey("SongName", equalTo: title!)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) song(s).")
                // Do something with the found objects
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {
                        println(object.objectId)

                        let objects: PFObject = object as PFObject
                        let parseAudio: PFFile = objects.valueForKey("Songs") as! PFFile
                        let audioPath: String = parseAudio.url!
                        let urlParse: NSURL = NSURL(string: audioPath)!

                        player = AVPlayer(URL: urlParse)
                        println(player)
                        player.play()
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: check that your **urlParse** contains value or not

Comment: How can I do that if it keeps crashing?

Comment: Use `Exception Breakpoint`. It will land you on the line where it is crashing.

Comment: I am getting the error in the `let objects: PFObject = object as PFObject`

Comment: You are redeclaring objects there. Try,  let object = object as PFObject and then obviously change the line below it to  let parseAudio: PFFile = object.valueForKey("Songs") as! PFFile

Comment: I have gotten it to work, if i click song a it plays song a, if I click song b it plays song b, but if I click song a again it plays song b. How do I get it to play song a when song a is clicked regardless of the number of cells there are?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the exact error is I can only say that your issues most likely resides in this block:

```
            let objects: PFObject = object as PFObject
                    let parseAudio: PFFile = objects.valueForKey("Songs") as! PFFile
                    let audioPath: String = parseAudio.url!
                    let urlParse: NSURL = NSURL(string: audioPath)!
```

Converting `parseAudio` to a string for your `NSURL` isn't getting the content of the file for your media player. Try something like this:

```
let parseAudio: PFFile = objects.valueForKey("Songs") as? PFFile
parseAudio?.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) -> Void in

      if error == nil {
             // do what you need to with the music file which is contained in `data`
              let fullParseAudioFile = data

      } else if error != nil {

      println(error!.localizedDescription)

      }

  })
```

I haven't worked with the media player so I don't know what format you'll have to cast data to but you would now have the usable file instead of just a string representing the name of the file.